# Kubernetes kubectl not pruning resources with prune option

Tags: kubernetes

Versions: 1.12 , and 1.13

I am using `kubectl apply -f /directory-of-yaml files`

All the resources are labeld with provider=abc

when I delete one of the yaml files , and apply again , the resource is still there in cluster.

Command:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig=/kubeconfig apply -f ./kubernetes --prune -l provider=abc
```

Also tried:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig=/kubeconfig apply -f ./kubernetes --prune --all
```

Comment: Provide more details. Show all objects you create by    kubectl apply -f /directory-of-yaml file , then apply    kubectl --kubeconfig=/kubeconfig apply -f ./kubernetes --prune -l provider=abc and again show your resources. Are you sure 100% all resources have right label?

Comment: yes , i checked all the day , there is an issue on github as well , it only prune the non-namespaced resources

Comment: I also tried --all

Comment: i also tried , if you create a deployment by commandline and run the --all prune then it should dlete it as well?

Comment: looks like it only cleans thoese objects who are not namespaced